# What does Background Intelligent Transfer Service exactly do?

Tags: windows-10

Recently (about 2 weeks ago) I noticed sometimes my bandwidth is being eaten by BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service). I google'd about it and noticed people have guides on how to turn it off. Thing is, I don't want to turn it off without knowing what does it do because it may affect my system in some way. What does it exactly do? Is it the service responsible for the windows updates or something?

Comment: BITS is used by Windows Updates...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=Background+Intelligent+Transfer+Service+site%3Amicrosoft.com = [Background Intelligent Transfer Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968799(v=vs.85).aspx), [About BITS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362708(v=vs.85).aspx), etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BITS transfers files in the background using idle network bandwidth. If the service is disabled, then any applications that depend on BITS, such as Windows Update or MSN Explorer, will be unable to automatically download programs and other information.

Windows Update uses the Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) technology which downloads updates using idle bandwidth. This technology ensures that Windows Update downloads only when no other active download is in progress on the computer. This allows you to smoothly carry on day-to-day activities even while updates are being downloaded in the background.
It is not recommended to disable this service.

Comment: `If the service is disabled, then any applications that depend on BITS, such as Windows Update or MSN Explorer, will be unable to automatically download programs and other information.` That sure is not a bad thing. xD

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue but i recommend you to not disable it because disabling it can cause "disconnecting PC from internet". you can stop the service and set it to trigger manually. That's the best solution i have been come up with so far.